# Trying to upload my files in our hosting and encountered "Uninitialized string offset: 0"

Tags: php, mysqli, hosting

The version of my CI is 5.3 and I tried to change the php version of my hosting into 5.4. and I'm getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Uninitialized string offset: 0
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 122
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/exclurec/public_html/application/controllers/Login.php
>   Line: 8 Function: __construct
>
> File: /home/exclurec/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

I tried to check that file and this is the code. Any idea how can I fix this?

```
if ($this->hostname[0] === '/')
        {
            $hostname = NULL;
            $port = NULL;
            $socket = $this->hostname;
        }
```

Note: I uploaded my files into public_html

Comment: hostname is a string, not an array. and hostname is an empty string. What is `$this`?

Comment: @Jeff Strings in PHP are byte arrays, and it's possible to access characters in a string using array index notation.

Comment: Sir I dont know, it was already like that when I downloaded the CI files(5.3 version).. I didnt change anything

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yes, I (kind of) know. I suppose OP expected hostname to be an array. Since only comparing to a single character it's kind of the same, true...

Comment: @Angel, can you please specify what you mean by CI?

Comment: Also, can you include more of the `__construct` function?